# MySQL init.d script with different configuration file

Tags: mysql, replication, init.d

I have two instances of mysql running on a server. I need two different init.d scripts. The two instances have different configuration files `/etc/my.cnf` and `/etc/my-slave.cnf`. I copied the `/etc/init.d/mysql` files to `/etc/init.d/mysql-slave` and changed the `conf` parameter to `/etc/my-slave.cnf` but the mysql-slave service is still controlling the first instance of mysql. The `my-slave.cnf` configuration file is as follows:

```
[mysqld]
user            = mysql
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.ip.ip.ip.ip.sock
port            = 32866
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql.ip.ip.ip.ip
server-id=18861
master-host=ip.ip.ip.ip
master-connect-retry=60
master-user=repluser
master-password=*******
        replicate-do-db=spring_salast

[mysql.server]
basedir=/var/lib/mysql.ip.ip.ip.ip
```

Comment: What do you mean by "still controlling" - can you expand on the behavior that you're seeing?

Comment: `service mysql-slave start|stop|restart` will start, stop and restart the first instance of mysql. The one with configuration file `/etc/my.cnf`

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL instances are controlled by mysqladmin (from inside /etc/init.d/mysql-slave). Mysqladmin it have --defaults-file= ... where you will find socket option (at what instance should connect). You need to change the socket option in both mysql-slave.cnf and in the default file.

```
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld-slave.sock
```

I don't know what distribution you are running, but if you do not have a default file then you should specify one. Debian default file it looks like

```
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = xxxx
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I think you get the idea.

Comment: The socket parameter has been defined. Please check the conf file included in the question.

Comment: but not for mysqladmin. mysqladmin it will get the standard mysql.cnf file. Search in /etc/init.d/mysql-safe after mysqladmin and see if it have --defaults-file defined. If is defined, then look in that file and modify socket option. If not you should specify the default file as /etc/mysql-slave.cnf